# Jquery, append after the third div?

Tags: jquery, html, append

Is there any way to append this after the third `div`?

```
$("p").append('<input type="text">').insertAfter('#pregunta');
```

```
<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como se llama tu sitio</div> 
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi sitio se llama www.hola.com</div> 

<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como te llamas</div> 
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi nombre es Marcos</div> 

<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">¿Como se llama su empresa?</div> 
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Nuestro sitio es sobre equipo de computo... ¿Interesado?</div> 

<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como se llama tu perro?</div> 
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi Perrro se llama pirrurris</div>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique within the DOM.

Comment: You want to insert something after the 3rd `#pregunta`?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have 1 instance of an ID per page. Targeting by CSS class instead, you can use `$.eq()` to target the 3rd instance, then use `$.after()` to insert HTML after it.

```js
$('.pregunta_class').eq(2).after('<p>asdf</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como se llama tu sitio</div>
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi sitio se llama www.hola.com</div>

<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como te llamas</div>
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi nombre es Marcos</div>

<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">¿Como se llama su empresa?</div>
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Nuestro sitio es sobre equipo de computo... ¿Interesado?</div>

<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como se llama tu perro?</div>
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi Perrro se llama pirrurris</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).insertBefore($('div').eq(3));
```

```js
$('<div class="test">TEST</div>').insertBefore($('div').eq(3));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pregunta" class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como se llama tu sitio</div> 
<div id="respuesta" class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi sitio se llama www.hola.com</div> 

<div  class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como te llamas</div> 
<div class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi nombre es Marcos</div> 

<div  class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">¿Como se llama su empresa?</div> 
<div  class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Nuestro sitio es sobre equipo de computo... ¿Interesado?</div> 

<div  class="pregunta_class" style="color:red">Como se llama tu perro?</div> 
<div  class="respuesta_class" style="color:#0000FF">Mi Perrro se llama pirrurris</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### Attention!!
>
> - First of all, you shouldn't be using `ids` like that!
>     `ID` are only meant to be used one time in the DOM on a single element, `classes` are the ones you can use multiple times to define styles to multiple elements.
> - Secondly, keep your styles separated from your HTML. You can either implement it on your `<head>` by using this example below, if you don't have access to create files within your website:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .pregunta_class {color:red;}
        /* ... etc ... */
    </style>
</head>
```

> or create a `.css` file like `styles.css` and call it from your `<head>` which is the more practical and recommended way of doing it:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>`

---

If you want to **[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**, meaning putting a `<p>` **inside the 3rd element** at the end of it, you can do it like the example below:

```js
$('.pregunta_class:nth-child(3n)').append('<p>Agrega un elemento p</p>');
```

```css
.pregunta_class {color:red;}
.respuesta_class {color:#0000FF;}
.pregunta_class p {color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pregunta_class">Como se llama tu sitio</div> 
<div class="respuesta_class">Mi sitio se llama www.hola.com</div> 

<div class="pregunta_class">Como te llamas</div> 
<div class="respuesta_class">Mi nombre es Marcos</div> 

<div class="pregunta_class">¿Como se llama su empresa?</div> 
<div class="respuesta_class">Nuestro sitio es sobre equipo de computo... ¿Interesado?</div> 

<div class="pregunta_class">Como se llama tu perro?</div> 
<div class="respuesta_class">Mi Perrro se llama pirrurris</div>
```

Now if you want to put this element [**after**](http://api.jquery.com/after/) the 3rd but outside of the `question`, as an individual element, just change the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('.pregunta_class:nth-child(3n)').after('<p>Agrega un elemento p</p>');
```